# TF Eager Pretrained Models

Tags: tensorflow

With `tfhub` unable to support Eager execution and most (if not all) released trained models working with the default execution mode in TensorFlow, are there any sources / repositories of pretrained models like `VGGNet`, `InceptionV3` .etc that can be used with TF-Eager?